# Hide filesystem symbols used in a shared library from linking applications under gcc 8 WITHOUT specifying experimental filesystem linker flag

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, ld, gcc8

I have 3 cmake targets relevant to this problem in my project.

- Executable - The thing giving me filesystem linker errors
- Shared Library - Core library.  Originally used filesystem directly before it was abstracted
- Static Library - naive attempt to abstract filesystem symbols hidden under private implementations and various different linker configurations.  Not successful.

I do not want to require my GCC 8 consumers to require the flag `-lstdc++fs` but I also want to use the "experimental" yet not std::filesystem.

No matter what I do I still get this when linking the executable:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable g++-8.3.1/bin/executable-d
g++-8.3.1/lib/libShared-d.so: undefined reference to `std::filesystem::status(std::filesystem::path const&)'
g++-8.3.1/lib/libShared-d.so: undefined reference to `std::filesystem::filesystem_error::~filesystem_error()'
g++-8.3.1/lib/libShared-d.so: undefined reference to `std::filesystem::path::replace_extension(std::filesystem::path const&)'
g++-8.3.1/lib/libShared-d.so: undefined reference to `std::filesystem::path::replace_filename(std::filesystem::path const&)'
g++-8.3.1/lib/libShared-d.so: undefined reference to `std::filesystem::path::_M_find_extension() const'
g++-8.3.1/lib/libShared-d.so: undefined reference to `std::filesystem::path::compare(std::filesystem::path const&) const'
g++-8.3.1/lib/libShared-d.so: undefined reference to `std::filesystem::filesystem_error::_M_gen_what()'
g++-8.3.1/lib/libShared-d.so: undefined reference to `std::filesystem::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
g++-8.3.1/lib/libShared-d.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::filesystem::filesystem_error'
g++-8.3.1/lib/libShared-d.so: undefined reference to `vtable for std::filesystem::filesystem_error'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

```
objdump -TC libShared-d.so 

libShared-d.so:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000      D  *UND*  0000000000000000              vtable for std::filesystem::filesystem_error
```

etc.

I do not understand why this symbol is trying to be exported.  Filesystem is not exposed anywhere on the API.  Side question: Is this because the gcc 8 filesystem is in an external library?

Realistically I want to have my cake and eat it, but I want to believe this is possible.

I have tried:

stripping the static lib `strip --strip-unneeded libStatic-d.a`

All of this junk on the Static lib (usually not all at the same time when I was testing)

```
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden")
    set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
    set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS_RELEASE -s)
    target_link_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE "-fvisibility=hidden")
    target_link_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE "--version-script=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/export-symbols.version")
```

and

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} 
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND strip --strip-unneeded  $<TARGET_FILE:${TARGET_NAME}>
)
```

This on the Shared Lib

```
    target_link_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE "--exclude-libs,ALL")
    target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE "-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL")
```

Maybe I'm just ignorant and need someone to correct me.

---

Edit:

ldd output

```
ldd libShared-d.so
libShared-d.so:
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd791b7000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb088e40000)
        libicuuc.so.50 => /lib64/libicuuc.so.50 (0x00007fb088ac7000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb0887bf000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb0884bd000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb0882a7000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb08808b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb087cbd000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb0899b5000)
        libicudata.so.50 => /lib64/libicudata.so.50 (0x00007fb0866ea000)
```

---

Edit 2:

```
ldd -d libShared-d.so
libShared-d.so:
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1c158000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f28aadf6000)
        libicuuc.so.50 => /lib64/libicuuc.so.50 (0x00007f28aaa7d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f28aa861000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f28aa559000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f28aa257000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f28aa041000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f28a9c73000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f28ab96c000)
        libicudata.so.50 => /lib64/libicudata.so.50 (0x00007f28a86a0000)
undefined symbol: _ZNSt10filesystem16filesystem_errorD1Ev       (./libShared-d.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTINSt10filesystem16filesystem_errorE        (./libShared-d.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTVNSt10filesystem16filesystem_errorE        (./libShared-d.so)
```

Comment: All the manipulations with the static lib make no sense to me. Static libraries just don't work this way. Now about dynamic libraries, the cmake stuff just muddies the water. Skip the cmake, show actual compiler invocations with all the arguments. Last but not least, the filesystem library is a part of C++17 and is not experimental for about 6 years now, and gcc8 is just about that much old too, perhaps it's time to upgrade?

Comment: Now to the problem itself. `std::filesystem` symbols in your implementation reside in `libstdc++fs.so`. No amount of fiddling with compiler options is going to change that. The only thing you can hope to achieve is a *shared* (never static) library that links to `libstdc++fs.so`, so that the executable doesn't need to. To check, run `ldd libShared-d.so`. Do you see `libstdc++fs.so` in the output?

Comment: It is not in the output - I'll add it to the edit section of question for formatted copy of the output.  I wish I could remove some of the older compilers, we are required to support them for a while longer though.

Comment: After trying `ldd -d libShared-d.so` from the manual (also added) and reading your comments helped me realize my mistake.  libShared-d itself, despite compiling and linking without errors, doesn't actually know where filesystem lives.  Like you said, it's not the application that needs the linkage, it's the lib itself.  Linking libShared-d to libstdc++fs does solve the problem and from testing it does not mandate that library consumers or applications specify this linkage.  So it turns out I was pretty ignorant.

Comment: Note: always build with `target_link_options(LINKER:--no-undefined)`

Comment: @Osyotr I did not know that was a thing.  Thank you, I'll add it.